# Submit and handle two forms with one handleSubmit in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, forms, react-hook-form

In my react app, I have two address forms on one page that have two save address functions which save the address in the database. There's also one submit button that submits both two fields and navigates to the next page (*The plus button in the circle adds the address to the saved addresses list*):

[image]

What I want to do is to validate the form fields and I'm already doing that by calling two instances of the `useForm()` hook:

```
// useForm hook
  const {
    control: senderControl,
    handleSubmit: handleSenderSubmit,
    setValue: senderSetValue,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      senderName: '',
      senderLastName: '',
      senderPostalCode: '',
      senderPhone: '',
      senderAddress: '',
    },
  });

  // useForm hook
  const {
    control: receiverControl,
    handleSubmit: handleReceiverSubmit,
    setValue: receiverSetValue,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      receiverName: '',
      receiverLastName: '',
      receiverPhone: '',
      receiverPostalCode: '',
      receiverAddress: '',
    },
  });
```

I've then added the handleSubmit method of these two hooks to the onClick (*`onPress` in RN*) of the plus button for each field respectively.

This does indeed validate the forms individually but the problem arises when I'm trying to submit the whole page with the **SUBMIT** button.

I still want to be able to validate both of these two address fields when pressing the general **SUBMIT** button but I have no idea how I can validate these two instances with one `handleSubmit` and get the `return data` of both fields' values.

**EDIT (CustomInput.js):**

```
const CustomInput = ({
  control,
  name,
  rules = {},
  placeholder,
  secureTextEntry,
  keyboardType,
  maxLength,
  textContentType,
  customStyle,
}) => (
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    rules={rules}
    render={({field: {onChange, onBlur, value}, fieldState: {error}}) => (
      <View style={customStyle || styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          value={value}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          textContentType={textContentType}
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
          style={[
            styles.textInput,
            {
              borderColor: !error
                ? GENERAL_COLORS.inputBorder
                : GENERAL_COLORS.error,
            },
          ]}
        />
        {error && <Text style={styles.errMsg}>{error.message || 'error'}</Text>}
      </View>
    )}
  />
);
```

**Usage:**

```
<CustomInput
    control={control}
    name="senderPostalCode"
    rules={{
      required: 'Postal Code is Required',
    }}
    placeholder="Postal Code"
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    textContentType="postalCode"
    customStyle={{
      width: '49%',
      marginBottom: hp(1),
    }}
/>
```

Is there even any way this can be possible at all?

Comment: In your case I think you should have only 1 SUBMIT button and 2 SAVE buttons. Please refer to a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rdkzpc

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev Thanks a lot for your advice. It is indeed helping me with the issue but for some reason, the errors that are set with `setError` don't get updated upon another instance of validation. I'm using the `Controller` from `react-hook-form` and have created a `CustomInput` to handle them.

Comment: can you post your code please.

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev I've edited the question with the `CustomInput.js` which I use to handle the input fields.

Comment: please also post code with usage of  `CustomInput.js`. I think I am staring understand the problem.

Comment: I've update the question.

Comment: weird @Nima I've updated example and it seems to be working https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rdkzpc

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev It is indeed weird. Your example works as expected but for some weird reason the field doesn't listen to changes for me. The only way I was able to fix it was calling `useWatch({control, name: 'senderPostalCode'})` and then validating the field with `setError` in the `save` button as you advised. Even then, that wouldn't cause the revalidation to trigger and the invalid input wouldn't attach `onChange` event listeners to re-validate it.  So I used the `trigger` method to manually trigger event listeners to re-validate it after pressing the `save` button.

Comment: I'll post the solution soon.

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev Thanks a lot for your help and advice. I have posted the solution which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks to @TalgatSaribayev 's comment for leading me to this solution.*

*I didn't need to set any specific validation rules for the address field and in the end I separated the sender and receiver forms into two different pages.*

First, I've got to point out that instead of getting the input values of `postalCode` and `address` fields with the `getValues` [API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues), I used the `useWatch` [hook](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch) to get the most updated values.

```
// Watch inputs
const watchedInputs = useWatch({
  control,
  name: ['senderPostalCode', 'senderAddress'],
});
```

When I saved the input values with `getValues` in a variable, I got the previous state instead of the most recent one and the only way to solve that was calling `getValues('INPUT_NAME')` whenever I wanted to get the most recent one. Even then I needed to call an instance of `useWatch` without saving it in any variable to keep track of the changes since typing in the input fields wouldn't update the `getValues` at all. So in the end I resolved to use `useWatch` and store its values in a variable and use that to access the values of the input fields.

**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

As @TalgatSaribayev pointed out, creating just one `useForm` instance was sufficient enough. All I had to do was to create a function which would set the errors manually and check their validation upon pressing the save address button.

```
// Check if sender postal code input has error
const senderHasError = () => {
  if (!/^\d+$/.test(watchedInputs[0])) {
    setError('senderPostalCode', {
      type: 'pattern',
      message: 'Postal Code must be a number',
    });
    return true;
  }
    
  // Any other rules
  if (YOUR_OWN_RULE) {
    setError('senderPostalCode', {
      type: 'custom',
      message: 'CUSTOM_MESSAGE',
    });
    return true;
  }
    
  // Clear error and return false
  clearErrors('senderPostalCode');
  return false;
};
```

The problem was that the errors wouldn't get updated (cleared) even when they had passed the validation. As if the invalid input wouldn't attach `onChange` event listeners to re-validate it. Something that happens as default when you submit the form with the `onSubmit` mode of `useForm`. (https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform)

So I resolved to use the `trigger` [API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger) of `useForm` to manually trigger form validation and listen for the changes on the `postalCode` field when the save address button is pressed.

First I created a toggle state which changes the trigger state:

```
// Postal code onSubmit event state
const [triggered, setTriggered] = useState(false);
```

Then used the `trigger` API of `useForm` in a `useMemo` to trigger the input validation only if the `triggered` state is set to true and the input field's value has changed:

```
// Manually trigger input validation if postal code's onSubmit event is true
useMemo(() => {
  if (triggered) trigger('senderPostalCode');
}, [watchedInputs[0]]);
```

I assume the way I triggered the input field with the `trigger` API works the same way as `useForm`'s mode of `onSubmit` does it under the hood: Starting the trigger when the user presses the save address button by changing the `trigger` state with `setTrigger`.

```
// Add address to sender favorites
const handleAddSenderFavAddress = () => {
  // Trigger on the press event
  setTriggered(true);

  // Return if sender postal code input has error
  if (senderHasError()) return;

  // SAVE ADDRESS LOGIC
  ///////////////////////////////
};
```

This was the only way I managed to validate separate input fields apart from the general validation that occurs with `useForm`'s `handleSubmit` [function](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit).

I welcome any more answers that might lead to a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a single instance of useForm hook and register all your fields in both the forms using the same register method.

This way whenever you click on submit, it will fetch the values from all the fields registered in different forms using the same register method.

Have attached a [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dijkstra-f8oecy?file=/src/App.js:285-794) for your reference

Comment: The problem is that I need to validate the input upon saving the addresses as well.

Comment: You can validate the fields using resolvers provided in useForm hook. I have updated the code in the code sandbox link for your reference. I am using a third party validation library called yup for validations.